# Why is this SQLite database not working

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to add a top 10 high scores to my game. The high scores are made of only two things - the score and the difficulty, but so far I don't understand very much how this database works but after several tutorials I have this done

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "highscores";

private static  final String TABLE_DETAIL = "scores";

private static  final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static  final String KEY_TIME = "time";
private static  final String KEY_DIFFICULTY = "difficutly";


public DBHandler(Context context){ super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_HIGHSCORES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DETAIL + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_TIME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_DIFFICULTY + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_HIGHSCORES_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DETAIL);     

    onCreate(db);                                          
}
// Adding new score
public void addScore(int score) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_TIME, score); // score value

    // Inserting Values
    db.insert(TABLE_DETAIL, null, values);

    db.close();

}

// Getting All Scores
public String[] getAllScores() {

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DETAIL;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list

    int i = 0;

    String[] data = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        data[i] = cursor.getString(1);

        i = i++;

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return score array
    return data;
}
}
```

And here is the class that I want to control the database from

```
public class highscores extends Activity {     

private ListView scorebox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
    scorebox = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorebox);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscores);
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addScore(9000);
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
}
}
```

When I open the page with the high scores in the application - it is blank, how to make it display something, I tried with this command `db.addScore(9000);` but it doesn't work. Maybe I didn't told the database where to display that data ?

Comment: `String CREATE_HIGHSCORES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_DETAIL + "("` You miss a **space** after `TABLE`

Comment: I added that space, but it didn't change much, the page opens but it is again blank

Comment: You must insert some data, if you want to get some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the Highscore Class

```
public class highscores extends Activity {     
    private ListView scorebox;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscores);
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
    scorebox = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorebox);
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addScore(9000);
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    ArrayList<String>ar=new ArrayList<>();
    ar=db.getAllScores();
    ArrayAdapter<String>ar=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
    scorebox.setAdapter(ar);
}
}
```

Now in Your DBHandler class Edit getAllScores() method like this

```
public ArrayList getAllScores() {

// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DETAIL;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list


ArrayList<String>data=new ArrayList<>();

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    data.add(cursor.getString(1));


}
cursor.close();
db.close();
// return score array
return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked finally, initially I got an error at `ArrayAdapter<String>ar=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);` saying the ar is already used and it can't find s but I managed to deal with those myself

Answer (score 0):

if you are using emulator you can pull the db file and check if the table is created or not, if you are using a device you can use this command

cd /D D:\Android\SDK\platform-tools // android sdk path

adb -d shell

run-as com.pkg.pkgname

cat /data/data/com.pkg.pkgname/databases/highscores >/sdcard/highscores

it will copy your db file to device sd card. Using [Sqlite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) you can open the db file and check the table is created or not. 
Also uninstall the app and install it again

Comment: I use emulator and I checked, the database does gets created. I see highscores, highscores-journal files in the data folder

Answer (score 0):

Use this to  list your score in your listview

```
public class highscores extends Activity {     

    private ListView scorebox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscores);
        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
        scorebox = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorebox);
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addScore(9000);
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        String []s=db.getAllScores();
        ArrayAdapter<String>ar=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
        scorebox.setAdapter(ar);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I get an error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: or use ArrayList instead of String

Comment: Here is a picture of the catlog because I couldnt write it in a comment http://image.prntscr.com/image/18493c9b0cfa434490556c65f667959c.png

Comment: Improved answer added